# how to put the breakpoint in opencv library

Tags: c++, opencv

currently, i'm working to develop the object detection by using ORB opencv library in visual studio. I want to modify `orb.cpp` that located in the features2d source. Once i put the breakpoint at this class, it doesn't work. I want to know how this algorithm works by putting the beakpoint at this class. Probably anyone know how to put the breakpoint in opencv library or any other way to do that? Thanks

Comment: It is possible this has been compiled heavily optimized and without any debug information so the debugger doesn't have a clue how to line up the nice and pretty human readable code with the binary mess that an optimizing compiler leaves behind. See if you can rebuild the library in a debug mode. There may be a convenient option you can set in a makefile.